# What does EdgeW mean in the Microsoft Edge useragent

Tags: android, microsoft-edge, user-agent

Take the following useragent:

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; SM-G991B Build/RP1A.200720.012; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/91.0.4472.120 Mobile Safari/537.36 **EdgW/1.0**

What does EdgW mean?

- EdgA means its Edge on Android
- EdgiOS means its Edge on IOS

(source: https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2017/10/05/microsoft-edge-ios-android-developer/)

but what does EdgW mean?  Especially given that the useragent states that the user is using an Android device

Comment: Could you please tell us on which kind of Android device that you get the user agent? I test on Xiaomi Mi 10, and I get `EdgA/45.09.4.5079`. Besides, could you please check the version number of Edge browser on that device? Edge on mobile now uses the new chromium engine, the version number should be 45, it's strange that you get `1.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we believe that this is an Edge WebView (this is just a guess so far)
https://github.com/matomo-org/device-detector/issues/6636

Comment: Yeah, just verified by opening a what's my useragent link from outlook app on Android and got this back: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; SM-G988B Build/RP1A.200720.012; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/91.0.4472.120 Mobile Safari/537.36 EdgW/1.0

Comment: it seems that the WebView is not always substituted in the UA
![screenshot](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1337066/124758186-ff563580-df36-11eb-9c73-4f4e09467680.png)

perhaps this is available in the new version of the browser